# invertibility of sums of tensor products of invertible matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, tensor-products

Lets say $A, B$ and $C$ are invertible, linearly independent $d\times d$ matrices. Then is $A^{\otimes n} + B^{\otimes n} + C^{\otimes n}$ invertible for $n\gg d$ ? Thanks

Comment: Seems it is not, in general. The counter example being $I^{\otimes n} + Z^{\otimes n} $ ($Z$ is the sigma-z matrix). It has eigen values of the form $1+(-1)^n$ which can be zero.